# How to set an unknown amount of index integers of an array to variables

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

i have an array with n amount of objects in it(lets say n = 1) and a forEach function that will execute another function every time it loops(basically, the amount of objects in the array is how many times its called). but heres the trouble, i need to assign each index integer of the array to a variable so i can pass it into other functions. does anyone know how i could do this(the loop does not have to be a forEach)?

I have tried setting the index of array to a variable, but this eventually resolves to the final index, and i need every index set to a variable.

```
let tasks = {"options":[{"headless":false"},{"headless":true}]};

tasks.options.forEach(function(value, int) {


    //the function called every${int}times
    main();

    //this returns 1 if there is 2 objects. i need to be able to have a variable(s?) that equals tasks.options[0]
    //and tasks.options[1] simultaneously
    let check = tasks.options[int]


});
```

Comment: I am not sure what you mean - If you dont know how to return 2 things at once, try an array with 2 elements, e.g. return [tasks.options[0], tasks.options[1]].
If you want your main function only to be executed every x time, you can use % (modulo) for that e.g. if (int % 5 === 0) main(); in order to call main() every fifth time

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use a json object? I'm not sure if that's what you need, but you can make it so every json element would equal something that is from the array, `{"0": i[0], "1": i[1] "3": i[2], "4": ...}`

```
let jsonObj = JSON.parse("{}");

tasks.options.forEach((value, int)) => {
    jsonObj[int.toString()] = value;
}
```

would be my best example.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: i was having an issue with the use of my forEach() loop in regards to the puppeteer module and feeding different JSON values to multiple puppeteer.launch(
) executions. I instead used a for loop and defined my function inside of the for loop. this solved any problems. i apologize for the confusion and thank you to all. time to return the favor to the community :)